# lazy loading at angular is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ProductModule

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

lazy loading at angular is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ProductModule!
I say every guide and still problem i must your profession help how to think it .

i share a code -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'product', loadChildren: () => import('./product/product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'product/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/home/home.component';
import { FavoriteComponent } from 'src/app/favorite/favorite.component';
import { AccountComponent } from 'src/app/account/account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from 'src/app/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from 'src/app/register/register.component';
import { InfoComponent } from 'src/app/info/info.component';
import { guards } from 'src/app/store/guards';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: guards },
  { path: 'favorite', component: FavoriteComponent, canActivate: guards },
  { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: guards },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

entire problem

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
    at JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (compiler.js:25915)
    at compiler.js:25891
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:25888
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25877)
    at compiler.js:25808
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25769)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

AppModule as asked from me , hope it will help you to find my problem

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './shared/modules/app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { RouterStateSerializer, StoreRouterConnectingModule, RouterState } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { reducer, CustomSerializer } from './storeRouter';

import { reducers, effects } from './store';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';
import { InfoComponent } from './info/info.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FavoriteComponent,
    InfoComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      routerState: RouterState.Minimal,
    }),

    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),

    StoreModule.forRoot(reducer, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: false,
        strictActionImmutability: false,
        strictStateSerializability: false,
        strictActionSerializability: false,
      },
    }),

    StoreModule.forFeature('products', reducers),

    // Only a tool for developers will delete on products
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25,
      logOnly: environment.production,
    }),

  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomSerializer }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If need more info i glad to add but i must your help Thank a lot!!

Comment: you have login component in declaration of appmodule and productmodule?

Comment: i edit my problem

Comment: Can you share your appmodule?

Comment: Move components which you have in route config of products module from declarations of app module to declaration of productmodule

Comment: i add all config i have , do you want maybe my git link to see?

Comment: i am not asking to add any config. just read what i have written again.

Comment: In your code do this :- Move components which you have in route config of products module from declarations of app module to declaration of productmodule

Comment: i fixed both your modules below. please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/home/home.component';
import { FavoriteComponent } from 'src/app/favorite/favorite.component';
import { AccountComponent } from 'src/app/account/account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from 'src/app/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from 'src/app/register/register.component';
import { InfoComponent } from 'src/app/info/info.component';
import { guards } from 'src/app/store/guards';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: guards },
  { path: 'favorite', component: FavoriteComponent, canActivate: guards },
  { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: guards },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     HomeComponent,
     FavoriteComponent,
     AccountComponent,
     LoginComponent,
     RegisterComponent
     InfoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

**Appmodule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './shared/modules/app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { RouterStateSerializer, StoreRouterConnectingModule, RouterState } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { reducer, CustomSerializer } from './storeRouter';

import { reducers, effects } from './store';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';
import { InfoComponent } from './info/info.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      routerState: RouterState.Minimal,
    }),

    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),

    StoreModule.forRoot(reducer, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: false,
        strictActionImmutability: false,
        strictStateSerializability: false,
        strictActionSerializability: false,
      },
    }),

    StoreModule.forFeature('products', reducers),

    // Only a tool for developers will delete on products
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25,
      logOnly: environment.production,
    }),

  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomSerializer }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: when i delete my   declarations: [], i have that problem  "core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module."

Comment: we are talking about logincomponent, not homecomponent

Comment: i know this what happend when i delete declarations

Comment: why only navbar is there ?

Comment: hard question , nothing work but i create a new project and copy all thinks from my last one and it work as i did i just want to know what the difference and if i need to change as you did above^

Comment: that means your site isn't properly configured, the components which are used in a single module should be part of declarations of that particular module, if any component is used in multiple modules, it should follow the idea of a shared module.

Comment: wow thank you , it fix my problem as well . how can i check if it really run as lazy mode?

Comment: launch your app, press f12 in browser. go to network tab. then activate your product link. you will see a js bundle getting downloaded. vote up the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: thank. i can't vote i need 15 reputation , thank you a lot

Comment: @Lolix, happy to help.